# Camera Shake in 3d video games

Tags: game-engine, camera

I am making a 3rd person game in the blender game engine and I noticed that most 3d adventure games (Ocarina of Time, Super Mario 64) do not hold the camera exactly behind the player. Instead, the camera will loosly follow the player. I made the player the parent of the camera so, obviously, it will not naturaly bob around. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the "slow parent" settings. They are found under *Properties > Object > Relations Extras*. Open them up under the camera and turn the offset up to, say, 9.00. This will give a lot of drag between your camera following the player; When the player moves, the camera follows loosely, just like you wanted. If you want a longer time between parent movement ad the child movement, increase the offset, less time, decrease the offset.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks! It worked. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Increase the delay value to lengthen the time needed for the camera to reach proper position.

Comment: Thanks X-27, adding to answer, (if IE will cooperate...:))

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid anymore in 2023 with Blender 4.0...

Comment: @eobet as of update 2.8, the blender game engine is entirely discontinued...