# How Can I make the Camera follow an object but with a delay?

Tags: game-engine, camera, parent

I can get the camera to follow the object when it moves, but I would like the camera to be delayed so it moves slightly after the object moves, instead of that ridged movement where it all moves at the same time.

Comment: Use slow parent, related question [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26947/camera-shake-in-3d-video-games/26949#26949](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26947/camera-shake-in-3d-video-games/26949#26949)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/75099/29586

Comment: @Strapicarus I didn't know about that Slow Parent and always achieved this kind of effect with Drivers. It's worth pointing out that any animation based on Slow Parent should be baked with Bake Action (as for Drivers)and the Slow Parent then disabled so that each frame has a consistent state - otherwise running the animation in reverse or jumping to specific frames produces different results. Pretty neat feature though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow parent needs to be enabled, and then set it to the amount of slowness you want the camera to lack behind. My English is terrible and I can't think of another way to word that.